# How to access a parameter in jrxml file and Print it?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My query is, I have set a parameter in my java file like given below

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("ReportTitle", "MRSG Quarterly Report");
```

How to access this in my jrxml file and Print it as a text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare the parameter in your jrxml

```
 <parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String"></parameter>
```

Then call it in a text field

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">               
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{"ReportTitle"}]]>
  </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: where to add this line "<parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String"></parameter>" in .jrxml file?. i am getting  error           "Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. Parameter not found : "ReportTitle""

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the select (sql report) a parameter and then use it as a Field, lika this:

```
<![CDATA[SELECT $P{FechaFin} as fechaFinal, ....]]>
```

You can use fechaFinal as a Field and print it in your report.